# Is it possible to manipulate $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(\frac{x}{2^k})$ into Euler's Product for Sinc Function?

Tags: infinite-product

I am interested to see if the product for the sinc function that is derived through the double angle formula: $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)$$

can be manipulated into Euler's Product for the sinc: $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)$$

I attempted to introduce the taylor series for cosine but I am left with a complicated product of an inifnite sum and I do not know where to continue further.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I doubt that, unless we're speaking of a **very** wide sense of "manipulate". I mean, if you're just using the fact that $n=(2k-1)2^l$ and the Euler product of $\cos x$, it would be elementary, but I'd rather call that "cheating".

Comment: I just want to see if I can derive it without resorting to Weierstrass factorization.

Comment: Hmm, you could try to show that both products have the same set of zeros and that they behave the same at $x=\infty$. then employing one of the mighty theorems of complex analysis (i forgot the name) would settle the case

Comment: Well, if you want to do that without complex analysis, that's possible, but rather tedious and technical. You don't use just that $\sin2x=\sin x\cdot 2\cos x$ (as you did), but $\sin(n+1)x=\sin x\cdot U_n(\cos x)$, and the factorization of the polynomial $U_n$ due to its known zeros, and then you let $n\to\infty$... but it's not really **that** pretty.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(x)
&=\frac{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}{\frac{\sin(x)}x}\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I just realized that this helps to prove the opposite direction.